# wpf The type name 'App' does not exist in the type ... occurs after renaming MainWindow

Tags: wpf

In a simple WPF, I have renamed MainWindow class to MyClass and I got this error in App.g.cs:

```
    public static void Main() {
        MyClass.App app = new MyClass.App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
```

How can I fix this can't find anything on the internet ?

Comment: Is `App` a nested class inside `MyClass`?

Comment: Or maybe `MyClass` is a namespace ? `MyClass.App app` looks weird to me.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I accidentally got this error, in my case I had a class with the same name as the namespace. Renaming the class solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Johan, I had this problem too just now.  What a fantastically stupid reason to give an error.

Comment: For more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/

Comment: Seems so unlikely yet so common error! Same was the case with me.

Comment: I just ran into this because I named a usercontrol the same name as my project

Answer (score 17):

**[Do not name a class the same as its namespace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)**

Check out if you don't have a class somewhere in your project that has the same name as your namespace!

for example:

```
namespace HashCalculator
{
  public class HashCalculator
```

Answer (score 4):

App.g.cs is produced by compiling App.xaml into C# code. The problem is in your App.xaml. Without seeing it, I can't be sure exactly what, but you probably just need to alter the StartupUri to `StartupUri="MyClass.xaml"`.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to change the classname in MyClass.xaml (or MainWindow.xaml).

change it from

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
```

to

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MyClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Johan's answer + Also check if you have a folder with the same name as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to install the .NET Framework 4.8 Runtime and Targeting Pack.